What Korean words have an "S" sound in them? What are example of words, in the Korean language, that contain the voiceless alveolar sibilant?
Many words in the English language contain a sound known as the voiceless alveolar sibilant
Examples of English words beginning with the voiceless alveolar sibilant are shown below:



ENGLISH
KOREAN




she
여성


say
말하다


sew
꿰매다


saw
톱


sumSUM
가득한합집합합계총


someSOME
비어 있는 것보다 더 큰 것은 무엇이고, 가득 찬 것보다 더 작은 것은 무엇일까요?


still
가라앉히다


sword
검


soon
더 빠르거나 곧


such that
~에 의해조건과 함께요구 사항과 함께


see
만나다 또는 응하다


seam
솔기 , 실밥 , ​상처 자국 , 꿰매다


stand
서다


speak
말하다


sing
노래하다





Are there any Korean words that contain a sound that is reminiscent of the voiceless alveolar sibilant?

What are some korean words that contain a sound very similar to the voiceless alveolar sibilant? the the sound does not have to be an exact match or perfect match.


The korean words 새, 새로운, and 생각에 all begin with an "S" sound or voiceless alveolar sibilant.
Hopefully, a different answer will be fielded by a different person with more than three examples of Korean words.




Korean sound for the earsandKorean writing for the eyes
Korean sound for the earsandEnglish writing for the eyes
English sound for the earsandEnglish writing for the eyes




새
s.eh.eeSEhEe
BIRDbird


새로운
SEhRUh-OONseh-r-uh-oo-n
NEWnewCLEANclean


생각에
sayn-gaw-gay
THINKINGthinking



